# Wanna downvote an answer on a question that's deleted? Here's your chance!

Tags: bug

This is probably still 10k only, but have at it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46453365/1228

I've never seen this before, and I'm pretty sure it's a bug, but that answer is on a deleted question, yet the answer displays like it isn't deleted and you can downvote it (yes, the downvotes remain after refresh).

Comment: Sorry, I ruined the opportunity. :) No idea off-hand what even happened there, but there's a rejected migration involved, so that's fun.

Comment: BOO!  Anyhow, bug it is!

Comment: @AdamLear It's a known oddity. When a migration gets rejected, the answers on the origin site get undeleted regardless of whether the question is deleted. But there is a process that automatically re-deletes them shortly later so it's never been a big issue.

Comment: I'm that frustrated that I had to DV this question now :-P. Otherwise it could have happen that my valves would be ruined.

Comment: @animuson fairly sure I've accidently undeleted an answer on a deleted question and it's been allowed but gets redeleted a little later - is that still the case?

Comment: @JonClements ah ah you're gaming the s/m.

Comment: I can't downvote it! It says "Page not found".